# How can I do push notifications in an HTML5 Web application?

Tags: javascript, html, push-notification, web-push, push-api

I have a web application. I want to use the HTML 5 inbuilt notifications API to do push notifications from the server when the user is on a particular page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do real push notifications with Web apps today in Chrome using [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) and [PushManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager) from the [W3C Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API).

See the article [Push Notifications on the Open Web](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web) for a step-by-step how-to and code snippets you can use. Here’s a diagram from that article that explains what the UI around it looks like.

[image]

An [implementation of the Push API has already landed in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1038811) too; it’s targeted for shipping in November 2015 in Firefox 42. And Microsoft has [indicated that the Push API is also under consideration for implementation in Edge team](https://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/pushapi/?filter=f3f0000bf&search=push) as well.

Below is a simple code example, borrowed from MDN.

```js
this.onpush = function(event) {
  console.log(event.data);
}

navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceworker.js').then(
    function(serviceWorkerRegistration) {
        serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe().then(
            function(pushSubscription) {
                console.log(pushSubscription.subscriptionId);
                console.log(pushSubscription.endpoint);
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: The client side is easy. What about the server side? Isn't that the meat of the question?

Comment: Is the google cloud messaging (firebase) approach only considered for chrome or does it also work for firefox?

Comment: @Vetterjack only chrome and android I believe

Comment: The tutorial here has information about how to handle the server side: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/ It involves using a technology that can handle large numbers of open connections at once.

Comment: You are only showing half part of the answer. You forgot server side

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you want to achieve:

- if you want to display a push notifications to the user while is surfing your website you can use the [Web Notifications API](https://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/), to give the notification a "native" style; you may also use a technology like SSE or WebSockets to push the notification from your server to the client
- if you want off-site push notifications (that are delivered even when the user is not on your website) you should use a combination of Service Workers and **Push API** to trigger the offline event and use the Notifications API to display the notification (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939698/how-can-a-web-application-send-push-notifications-to-ios-devices/34920874#34920874))