# How and what to use to push notification in front-end without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, laravel-5

i have a program in python that inserts data into database(xampp), i want to listen to any changes in the database and receive a request to frontend without using any click event. Something like ajax but only listen and notifies, and will automatically push notifies in front-end.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501619/how-can-i-do-push-notifications-in-an-html5-web-application

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript serviceworkers [Check this out](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/)

e.g

```
  self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
  console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: 
  "${event.data.text()}"`);

  const title = 'Push Codelab';
  const options = {
    body: 'Yay it works.',
    icon: 'images/icon.png',
    badge: 'images/badge.png'
  };

  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});
```

but you have to register the service worker first e.g

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
  console.log('Service Worker and Push is supported');

  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
  .then(function(swReg) {
     console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);

     swRegistration = swReg;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
     console.error('Service Worker Error', error);
  });
} else {
  console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');
}
```